# Pandas in Python 3 - Return list of highest sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to find the sum of each column in the dataframe below and return a list of the highest sums. I've tried to use the code below however it only reports the max number. How do I update to include the column label (or labels if there are multiple columns if more than one column equals the max).

```
grouped = df.sum()
mostPurchased = grouped.max()
print(grouped)
```

|  | snow suit | gloves | coat | boots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| january | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| february | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| march | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| april | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| may | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| june | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| july | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I want this to return:

Coat 3, Boots 3

Comment: kindly add data, not pics. Also include your expected output dataframe

Comment: Do you mean the sum of each rows ?

Comment: @fredaroo No, I'm looking for the highest sum of each column. Data table has been added for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns where the column sum equals the max column sum:

```
grouped = df.sum()
grouped[grouped == grouped.max()]
#coat     3
#boots    3
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This returns the sum for all columns and does not return only cost 3, boots 3.

Comment: Clearly, my example shows the opposite.